# how to auto inrease the id of <li> new elements in orderd list <ol>

Tags: jquery, html-lists, auto-increment

I want to auto increase the id of the new `li` elements in an ordered list when there is an increase in the numbering of the ordered list.I tried this but it did not work.

Plz help.

```
    var counter = 0;

    var html = "<div class='steps '><ol ><li class='personid'  id='"+  counter++   +"' ><a href='url-here' >Link Text </a></li></ol><div>";
    $('#redactor2').append(html);
```

Here is http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/rWcKu/1/

Comment: make sure that the `counter` is declared outside the scope of the function else the value will be reset to 0 every time

Comment: IDs cannot begin with digits.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have posted only seems to add one `<li>` item. However, assuming that you're going to be adding items in a loop, this should work to achieve what you need:

```
var html = '<div class="steps">\
                <ol>';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    html+= '<li class="personid"  id="person'+ (i + 1) +'"><a href="url-here">Link Text</a></li>';
}

html+ '</ol><div>';
$('#redactor2').append(html);
```

It's also worth noting that IDs cannot begin with numerals.

Comment: thanks,but I want to increse the id only when there is a new auto increase by  pressing inter.The code is working only in loop.but whenever li is creadted by enter press.id does not increases.

Comment: my purpose is to increase the id only when there is increase of the ol number by pressing enter.

Comment: here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/younis764/rWcKu/1/    the id must be increased whnever tere is new increase in  li numbering

Comment: Why not do: `for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)`? You don't have to start with 0 ;) I know we get so used to doing it though ;)